# is there a way in git to have a folder in the main branch which has all previous versions of a folder?

Tags: git, github, version-control, modeling

I am working on a computational model and running it on a university machine using ssh. It outputs data as a folder of text files, and I would like to store them neatly on git along with the code to avoid myself or anyone else having to run the same code again for hours just to get some data to work with.

Ideally, I would like to have all these output folders linked to the code that has generated them so it is easy to track the changes made to each run, but at the same time have them all in one folder on the main branch.

The closest thing I can think of is to have a linear workflow where in each commit there is one output data folder with the code that generated it, ensuring only one test output is ever present in the commit.

So, I guess the technical question may be, is there a way to have a folder in the main branch which has all previous commits of a folder? Any advice is greatly appreciated. I have attached a diagram, hopefully it helps clarify my question.

[Diagram of what I want vs traditional linear workflow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SJZqC.png)

Comment: Based on your diagram, you should just change the output location each time you make changes to the code. For example, in the first commit, output to `OriginalOutput`, in the second commit, you'd output to `Change1Output`, and in this case, `OriginalOutput` is left entirely unchanged and will still reside in your repository. This will make your repository unnecessarily big as you'll have a new folder for each change, but it's what you're asking for.

Comment: Thanks for you response! that makes sense, but is there a good way to organise how to get to the code for a certain output? I guess I could have a naming convention for output files and tags at each commit to add to the README, but that would end up being a lot of tags. I don't think the size will to much of an issue, the output files shouldn't be very big.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Ideally, I would like to have all these output folders linked to the code that has generated them so it is easy to track the changes made to each run, but at the same time have them all in one folder on the main branch.

Put each run into a sub-folder named in a way that associates it with the current build.

You could use the commit ID, like 91e645c1a8a2ff1edc788066ef02f349f959da20 would be `output/91e645c1a8a2ff1edc788066ef02f349f959da20/`. But then `git checkout 91e645c1a8a2ff1edc788066ef02f349f959da20` will check out a commit before the associated data was added. The user needs to hunt for a later commit which has the associated data.

Instead use release tags. The data associated with release v1.2.3 goes into `output/v1.2.3/`. Place the release tag on the commit which adds the output. Then `git checkout v1.2.3` will give both the code and its data.

These are unique, and so support parallel runs, and trace back to which build was used.

---

There are issues with committing this into the same repository as the code. Git clone downloads the complete history and all these historical data runs could get rather large and bloat the repository size.

One option is to have a separate, optional data repository which users can download if they like. This also avoids the problem of the data for a commit coming after the commit.

Another is to use [Git Large File Storage aka `git-lfs`](https://git-lfs.github.com/). This lets you commit large amounts of data to a repository while transparently storing it in the cloud. This lets users download the data as they need it instead of all at once.

*Do not* compress the data. Git will do that for you. Committing compressed data will hamper Git's ability to store the data efficiently.

Comment: Thanks! Lfs seems like a good approach, but it turns out my data is much larger than I initially expected, and it seems like lfs on github has quite limited bandwidth. My university provides unlimited google drive storage, so am thinking of just writing a script that will download the data from a google drive link.

Answer (score 0):

You can haul out all historical versions of a folder pretty easily, if your code's in `code` and its output data's in `code/data`,

```
for commit in `git rev-list @~ -- code`; do
        git read-tree -u --prefix=$commit/code $commit:code
done
```

and if you don't want the results in this commit follow up with e.g.

```
q8='????????'; git reset -- $q8$q8$q8$q8$q8
```

Getting the names prettier is up to you, instead of `$commit` in the prefix you could do `$((1000+n++))`

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything wrong with the linear flow you proposed since it's easy to look back at the history in Git. But to get what you want, I would handle it in the script that generates the output folder. Simply name those output folders with a datetime and the commit ID (or perhaps the first 10 characters of each commit ID) that generated it. Here is an example of some possible folder names:

```
Output-2021.05.28.170000-60110b27c8
Output-2021.05.28.180000-4dd529672c 
Output-2021.05.28.190000-1e577efbd1 
Output-2021.05.28.200000-37a048959d
```

You can use many different ways to get the current commit in your script. One way is:

```
git rev-parse HEAD
```

With folders named this way you can easily visualize the order in which the output was generated, and also easily find the output folder for a specific commit ID.